# Create a DataFrame from another DataFrame by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I would like to create a data frame from another data frame - but I want to do it by specifying the coordinates. In this case I want the new DataFrame to contain only the first column.

The following is correct in that it works:

```
US_effective_rate = US_forward_rates.iloc[:,1].copy()
US_effective_rate = US_effective_rate.to_frame()
```

I was wondering if there's a better implementation, possibly using .filter()?

there are similar questions but they reference column names, not coordinates.

thank you very much.

PS: I actually just want the dimensions and index from the first frame, going to overwrite the actual data. Any chance I could do THAT in one hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just add `[]`

```
US_forward_rates.iloc[:,[1]]
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you so much!